# How to match $123$, $$, $, but not $123 with regex?

Tags: regex, awk

I have a decently simple awk script that at point needs to look at a string and replace any instance of double dollar sign ($$), double dollar sign with numbers inbetween ($123$), and single dollar sign ($) with and _. I've done it very easily in two regex's with gsub, but I feel like I should be able to do it with one regex and its driving me crazy that I can't lock it down. Probably doesn't matter for time or speed but at this point I just have to know if I'm correct about there being a more condensed way or if I'm crazy.

Here is what I currently have:

```
gsub (/\$[0-9]*\$/, "_", $1);
gsub (/\$/, "_", $1);
```

I thought there was no problem with setting it up in one line using

```
gsub (/\$[0-9]*\$*/, "_", $1);
```

but I didn't realize there were instances of a single dollar sign follow by numbers ($123) where I only wanted to replace the dollar sign and not the numbers. So I need to match 1 dollar sign, then 0 or more numbers, then 1 dollar sign if numbers were matched, or 0 to 1 (or more, doesn't really matter) dollar signs if no numbers.

Edit: Sorry I didn't give a better example of input and desired output.

Input:

```
foo$bar$$foofoo$353$foobar$123
abc$123$xyz$$123abc$def$$hij$456$klm
```

Output:

```
foo_bar_foofoo_foobar_123
abc_xyz_123abc_def_hij_klm
```

Hope that's more clear on what I want.

Comment: `\$([0-9]+\$|\$?)`

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. It's particularly important to include cases that might be difficult for a script to get right and to include the context around the strings you want to match in the input and in the output (if you aren't removing it).

Comment: Are you trying to do this? 1. Split the string on separators consisting of one or more dollar signs. 2. Remove from the split list elements which consist of digits. 3. Join the remaining pieces using underscores as separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements aren't very clear but is this what you want?

```
$ awk '{sub(/\$([0-9]*\$)*/,"_")}1' file
_ - match
_ - match
_ - match
_123 - don't match
```

IDK if the above is the expected output or not given what I assume is your posted sample input:

```
$ cat file
$ - match
$$ - match
$124$ - match
$123 - don't match
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `awk` supports negative lookahead in its regular expressions, so you need to use program logic.

```
gsub(/\$[0-9]*\$/, "_", $1);
if ($1 ~ /\$/ && $1 !~ /\$[0-9]/) gsub(/\$/, "_", $1);
```

However, this won't work with a string like `$foo $123`, because `$123` prevents any substitutions being done.

If you're using GNU Awk, you can use its `gensub` function to use a capture group in the substitution. Then you can match `$` followed by something that isn't a digit, and copy the non-digit into the replacement.

```
gensub(/\$([^0-9]|$)/, "_\\1", "g", $1);
```